# Rotate icon on hover link

Tags: html, svg

I added link and icon after.

[image]

```html
<a class="link--primary" href="#">LINK<svg class="icon icon-arrow-right"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right"></use></svg></a>
```

How can I rotate icon on 90 deg, when hover on link?

Comment: I have exactly that, what I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
.link--primary:hover .icon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Rotate not supported by IE <= 8 and by Opera Mini. -> http://caniuse.com

**EDIT** Transition supported with prefix.

```
-webkit-transition: transform 1s;
-moz-transition: transform 1s;
transition: transform 1s;
```